# What combination of spells and items provide you the best odds of being undetectable?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, magic, stealth

If I were attempting to solo infiltrate a fortress by stealth, what spells/items would I bring to give me the best chance of not getting caught? If the fortress had unknown methods of detection, what should I bring to increase my odds of success?

Types of detection may include:

- Truesight
- Sound
- Movement
- Magic
- Smell
- Thoughts
- Intentions
- Alignment
- Any detection provided by official, published artifacts

Looking for RAW, nothing homebrewed.

Comment: I think this might be too broad and opinion based on what constitutes 'undetectable'. Should I include issues like, "can get past a closed door?" or is it just, "everything that a divination spell can detect?"

Comment: @Pyrotechnical added a small list to maybe help with this. Can feel free to edit/expand as you wish

Comment: I still think it may be too vague. Indeed, see doppelgreener's comments on T.J.L's answer, we don't know what level of defenses you're referring to exactly. If we include effects introduced by deific power, I can't see a way for a lowly player to have a chance, but if we don't then you could probably do a lot with a few key spells and specific skills with Expertise.

Comment: @A.B. A golden rule of thumb on Stack Exchange is that it is *always* helpful to be specific about the exact actual situation you personally are facing. It would help to know whether we're dealing with the king's very well guarded tower, or the Well-Watched Fortress of Eyes of the God of Omniscient Watchfulness And Detecting Everything All The Time, guarded around the clock by his All-Seeing Un-Resting Many-Eyed Servants with deity-forged Rings of X-Ray Vision.

Comment: @doppelgreener surely that Fortress exists, somewhere. I will attempt to edit the question

Comment: It *may* be better to adjust the question to magical means of avoiding detection. That's a very straightforward question.

Comment: A silver rule of thumb is to avoid inventing hypothetical situations for questions. It is better to ask what one is asking about directly, and say plainly the actual reasons for asking, than to cloak it in illusions that may fool the answerers in the wrong way than intended and give worse answers as a result.

Answer (score 3):

## No, you can't. But you can reduce your risk.

There are no guarantees in anything with 5e, but there are several items/spells that can assist in making it very hard to find you...

but the Dice may not be in your favor.

### Spells

1. Pass Without A Trace (PHB, 264)

   > For the duration, each creature you choose within 30 feet of you (including you) has a +10 bonus to Dexterity (Stealth) checks and can't be tracked except by magical means. A creature that receives this bonus leaves behind no tracks or other traces of its passage.
2. Nondetection (PHB, 263)

   > The target can't be targeted by any divination magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.
3. Invisibility/Greater Invisibility
4. Dimension Door (Move *very quickly* through. If someone detects you, can get out of there and far away very fast - fast enough for them to likely go about their business and assume it was a false positive detection.)
5. Etherealness (PHB, 238) - Danger on the material plane? Head to the Ethereal.

### Items

**(there are additional items that emulate some of the spells above I'm not listing)**

1. Amulet of Proof against Detection and Location (DMG, 150) - works like the Nondetection spell.
2. Boots of Elvenkind (DMG, 155) - Make no sound - ADV on stealth check to move silently.
3. Cloak of Elvenkind (DMG, 158) - Disadvantage on perception checks to see you, advantage on stealth checks to hide.
4. Ring of Mindshielding (DMG, 191) - Makes it impossible to know your alignment, if you're lying, or read your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

## Basics

Given the ability to cast **[Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)** to suppress any magical defenses, the only thing you really need to worry about is physical security measures. You'll want to make sure you're proficient in Athletics, Acrobatics, Stealth, and Thieves Tools. You can improve your bonuses with those abilities by pre-acquiring the appropriate Tomes to boost your Strength and Dexterity as high as possible; the effect is non-magical once it is in place and won't be affected by the **Antimagic Field**.

**Antimagic Field** is a relatively small radius, as spells go (only 10'). By the time anybody notices a suppressed magical defense, you should be close enough to deal with the individual physically. Your previously improved Strength and Dexterity will help here, too.

## Artifacts

The only published things you're vulnerable to are artifacts. Only the **Eye of Vecna** (*DMG* p224) presents any problems. It allows the bearer access to a function like the **Ring of X-Ray Vision** (*DMG* p193). It's limited to a range of 30', lasts one minute, and potentially causes Exhaustion unless combined with the **Hand of Vecna**. It is a possible complication, but unlikely even if Vecna actually exists in your game setting.

The question specifically excludes home-brew, so there's no need to fear from any other/unknown artifact or the powers of deities. That becomes pure house-rule territory.

Comment: I would consider magic suddenly not working to be quite noticeable. Especially if the place is rigged with many magical detectors/countermeasures.